# How can I overwrite where clauses in laravel query builder object?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, builder

Example I have query builder object

```
$queryBuilder = Products::where('price', '>', 100);
```

But if I need change where clauses to example - where('price', '<', 100).
How can I overwrite current where clauses in this object? Is it has way?

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel conditional Clause

```php
 ->when($yourCondition, function ($query) {
       $query->where('price', '>', 100);
  }, function ($query) {
       $query->where('price', '<', 100);
 })
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#conditional-clauses